# Android set system time not persistent after rebooting

Tags: java, android, adb

I have a problem setting the system time with an adb command. I have realized that the following function (that executes a "toybox date" command) works well in Android 8.1 and 9, but on Android 7.1.2 after rebooting the device, the device shows the time before the execution of the command (the previous time).

So, summarizing, the steps to reproduce the problem are:

1. Execute the following snippet (the time passed as parameter must be different to current system time)
2. Reboot the device
3. Check the device time. The device shows the time before changing the system time

Android OS:

- With Android 7.1.2: the system time set not persists after reboot (I have tested with 2 different devices)
- With Android 8.1 and 9: the system time set persists after reboot

The function to change system time:

```
public static void changeSystemTime(String year, String month, String day, String hour, String minute, String second) {
    Process process = null;
    try {
        String command = "su 0 toybox date " + month + day + hour + minute + year + '.' + second + '\n';
        process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        process.waitFor();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        MyLogger.add(Level.SEVERE, "UsefulTools, changeSystemTime: " + MyLogger.generateLogMessage(e));
    } finally {
        if (process != null)
            process.destroy();
    }
}
```

On my AndroidManifest.xml I have the permissions to set the system time:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_TIME"
    android:protectionLevel="signature|system"
    tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_TIME_ZONE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature|system"
    tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
```

I have tried to change the system time with the `date` command instead but happens the same.
Why this is happening? Any ideas to make the system set persistent?

Comment: Are the devices running 7.1.2 the same devices that you test later releases on? I know anecdotally that at least some older Android phones literally needed cell reception to set their real time clock each boot, because they had no battery-powered one.

Comment: I tried with 4 different devices. 2 with Android 7.1.2, one with Android 8.1 and one with Android 9. All the devices have no battery and are powered with cable, because are devices fixed to a wall

Comment: Usually systems without real-time clock work his way that they periodically save the current time to disk so that after next reboot they can pic-up at that point. May be Android 7 doesn't immediately save the newly changed time to disk and by directly rebooting the change is lost? How long do you wait after changing time?

Comment: I tried waiting 5 minutes and 2 hours, but the problem was the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. I will explain here if it could help somebody in the future.

I have tested these commands on Android 7.1.2 and work well, but on Android 8.1 does not work (but `toybox date` work well as I said).

There are system time and hardware time, and `toybox date` only changes the system time on Android 7.1.2. It is necessary to run these commands after the `toybox date` command to save the time to the hardware time too.
Run on ADB shell:

1. `hwclock -uw`
2. `sync`

And after rebooting the time persists.